# html 5 convertion and CSS ignored

Tags: php, css, html

Good day we have a already existing site in php. If I add the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This causes the CSS to be ignored and the site displays completely wrong. Any ideas? or what am I missing?

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Company</title>
   <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico"/>

<?

   $ua_ok= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if( eregi( "msie", $ua_ok ) )  
     {  

echo "<LINK REL='StyleSheet' TYPE='text/css' HREF='/styles.php'></LINK>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<LINK REL='StyleSheet' TYPE='text/css' HREF='/stylesOth.php'></LINK>";    
    }

<script language="JavaScript">

      </script>
      <script language="javascript" src="/scripts/jscripts.php<?=FindClass()?>">
      </script>
   </head>
<!--<body onload="window.history.forward(1);"> -->
```

All browsers are ignoring the CSS not only IE.

Page output has no CSS, the pages looks plain, no border, no colour, no overlay.

Gives error :

SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch 
styles.php

Comment: Can you post the complete code of the site?

Comment: ... or at least the entire `<head>` section?

Comment: Please show the *generated* HTML, not the PHP which generates it. Please also state which browsers ignore it. You have UA sniffing code in there.

Comment: The HTML you are generating is invalid (use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org)!). The PHP uses the the deprecated `eregi` function and the often disabled `<?` short tag.

Comment: Upper case tags/attributes; eregi; language attribute; onload attribute; short tags; coding style; indentation. Those all need fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give just another answer after your edit revealing the SEC7113 error: since your source file for CSS is php script, force the CSS header at the top of the `styles.php` and `stylesOth.php`

```
<? header("Content-type: text/css");?>
```

BTW: your code suffers some validity errors, you should really look at the links suggested by Quentin.

Comment: Hi thanks this enabled the css to be accepted , now the issue is only that the CSS does not display correctly as it should. will wun validation on CSS/

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing `?>` tag in the code here:

```
...
?>
<script language="JavaScript">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If adding a Doctype to a document stops CSS from working, then the CSS probably has errors in it that browsers will perform error recovery from when in Quirks mode.

These errors can usually be fixed by ensuring that the the CSS and HTML are both valid.

Use [a CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and a [markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to find these errors so you can fix them.